# Raw Type Warning in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, compiler-warnings

Android Studio doesn't show a compiler warning when using the raw type in referencing a generic type. Is there a way to enable this feature?

```
public class GenericClass<T> {
}

public class SpecificClass extends GenericClass {
}
```

Eclipse usually shows the following warning: *GenericClass is a raw type. References to generic type GenericClass <T> should be parameterized.*

Comment: Android Studio is built on IntelliJ, can you check if you can do this IntelliJ?

Comment: were you able to enable the feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable the warning but cant force it as compilation error. Same is the case in Eclipse[see tail for the update]. You can refer to [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) which states it compilation warning and not a compilation error.

You can enable the inspection in your android studio. Go to `File > Settings > Inspection` and turn on the check as for the "Raw use of parameterized class" setting as shown below may help:

[image: raw usage]

Thanks to Stephan: You can enable this in Eclipse using:
`Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Generic Types > Usage of a raw type`: and select `Error` in the combo

Comment: Works in the editor but wouldn't show in the project view as error.

Comment: @multiholle .. You can enable the warning but cant force it as compilation error. Same is the case in Eclipse. You can refer to JLS which states it compilation warning and not a compilation error. In your question you are asking for compiler warning and not compiler error.

Comment: For completeness: Eclipse does allow upgrading "rawtype" warnings to errors, which is a good choice actually, considering the havoc that raw types may cause. JLS also says: "It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types."

Comment: @stephanherrmann ... Thanks. Can you please share how I can do it? It will be helpful.

Comment: @Garry in the project's properties go to `Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Generic Types > Usage of a raw type:` and select `Error` in the combo.

Comment: Yay! In Android Studio 2.0 Beta 6, turning this on is a little confusing. In the first pane under "Java language level migration aids", you have to enable "Raw use of parameterized class". You can then customize the inspection in the second pane.