# Conversion error on derivated Factory using Class<T>

Tags: java, android-studio, generics, factory

The folowing miminal example resuts in an error "`Collection` cannot be converted to `LinkedList`" on Android Studio:

```
class Factory<F extends Factory<F>> {

   public <T extends Collection<?>> T empty(Class<T> clazz) {
       try {
           return clazz.newInstance();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new Error(e);
       }
   }

}

class MyFactory extends Factory {

   // ERROR is displayed here
   LinkedList<?> list = empty(LinkedList.class);  

}
```

I tried to remove that error but could not figure out what is the problem. The construct `T create(Class<T> clazz)` should be valid and worked for me many times. So conversion should not be the problem and the error was not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a fiew hours to create a minimal exmaple (my original project is more complex and involves Android specific code). When I copied the minimal example to eclipse, I recognized I forgot to add the template parameter on `MyFactory` to `extend Factory<MyFactory>`. Eclipse gave me a warning to extend a raw-type. That raw-type does not provide generic argument on member-function `empty()` and returns `Collection` instead of `T extends Collection`.

Android Studio actually can create a Warning on raw-types, but it is disabled by default. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561804/raw-type-warning-in-android-studio) for how to enable it.

I hope this helps someone who encounters the same problem.